# Creating a table in HTML to display the result of a query in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a PHP page to display the results of a query in a MySQL database under the format of a table. By spending quite some time on different forums, I ended with something that is somehow satisfying me but that is strongly affecting the design and the layout of my webpage. Due to the fact that I wrote the code by a test-fail strategy, it is far from being straightforward and I am sure it is possible to shorten and simplify it and, therefore, make it more compatible with the format of my webpage. Could anybody have a look at it and give some suggestions of general interest about how to solve this kind of issues?

```
  <div id="main">
  <?php
  require_once('../mysqli_connect.php');
  $response = $db->query("SELECT * FROM metabolite");
  echo '<table align="center" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5" border = "1">
  <tr><td align="center"><b>Metabolites</b></td>
  <td align="center"><b>KEGG Id</b></td>
  <td align="center"><b>Synonyms</b></td></tr>';
  while ($data = $response->fetch())
  {
  ?>
  <tr><td align="left">
  <?php echo $data['Metabolite_name']; ?></td>
  <td align="left">
  KEGG: <?php echo $data['Synonyms']; ?></td>
  <td align="left">
  <?php echo $data['Synonyms']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
  }
  $response->closeCursor();
  ?>
  </div>
```

I thank you in advance for all your effort and your help.

Tom.

Comment: What is the issue? Do you want to prettify your code?

Comment: Have you looked into CSS to control the design and layout of your webpages? See: http://learnlayout.com

Comment: Did you just vote my answer down Paul Spiegel?

Comment: @Kobbe No. But I probably should.

Comment: Looks like someone didn't get laid for a while.

Comment: Your code seems fine, if you want the table to better fit the design of your page, you should consider looking into creating a CSS stylesheet which would standardize the appearance of your table elements.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way we can improve the design and layout of your webpage with the code you've given us. What I can do is write 'better' readable code.

```
<?php

function tableCell($content)
{
  echo '<td align="left">'.$content.'</td>';
}

// database access 
require_once('../mysqli_connect.php');
// get all records from the metabolite table
$response = $db->query("SELECT * FROM metabolite");
// start main division
echo '<div id="main">';
// start the table
echo '<table align="center" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5" border = "1">';
// walk through all the metabolite records
while ($data = $response->fetch()) 
{
  // start a row
  echo '<tr>';
    // create the cells
    tableCell($data['Metabolite_name']);
    tableCell('KEGG: '.$data['Synonyms']);
    tableCell($data['Synonyms']);
  // finish a row
  echo '</tr>';
}
// close the table
echo '</table>';
// close main division
echo '</div>';
// close query
$response->closeCursor();
```

But this is not worth much, the output should remain the same.

Comment: Hi. I've seen that you mentioned in another post to use CSS to standardize the appearance and I did, that's how I know that the style is correct as I have no problem on another page that is not referring to any database but is more like some plain text. What I believe is that in the code I wrote I open and close several time php and that may interfere with the CSS layout in the HTML page. In what you're suggesting, you open it only once. I assume that I have to clase it after the last line by adding an extra ?>.
I will give it a try tonight. Many Thanks.

Comment: one last thing, if I understand correctly, in PHP, whenever I want to write something so that it is read as a normal HTML command (like for example create a table, add a line, write some text, ...), I just have to write echo '<>' and it is read outside PHP. All right?

Comment: 1. You can open and close PHP multiple times in one file, that should not be a problem. I don't like it, but that's just my opinion. 2. No, if you don't put any HTML, after you ended your PHP code, you don't have to close with a `?>`. See: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2 (which I don't all follow myself). 3. Yes, `echo`, and some other function, produce output, which is interpreted by the browser as html if you use the http protocol (= a webserver).

Comment: OK. Thank you very much for all these details. I gave it a try and I have some error message as you refer from the beginning of the code to $data (in the function), while it is defined later on. Anyway, this didn't help to improve the formatting. I may have done something wrong in defining the divisions. I will just restart from scratch. Thank you very much anyway for your help and your time.

Comment: Yes, stupid mistake. I didn't run the code, so I didn't spot it. I'll change the code to correct this. No, this doesn't help with the formatting. I hope you have gotten something from this: Good styling of your source code is important!

Comment: well, actually; by rewriting it, I noticed that I didn't close the table. It was as stupid as that...... Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're welcome. Not spotting things like a table close might be due to the poor coding style. Whenever I says this to people, they always tell me: "I'm not finished yet.", but that's not the point. A good coding style will help you spot these problems from the start, saving you hours of work. There are coding standards out there, see: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2 (bit overwheming at first, but it all make sense in the end)

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($response->num_rows > 0) {
    while($data = $response->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $data["Metabolite_name"]. "</td></tr>" . ;
        }
    }
else {
    echo "0 results";
    }
```